# Powershell - How can I put my .dat file into an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell

Trying to find the numbers in my file divisible by 3. How can I make my foreach loop read each number individually? I've bee trying to figure out how to put the file into an array, would that help me?

this is my file:

```
6 9 7   
-----   
5 2 9   
3 4 4   
1 6 9
```

This is my code so far:

```
function number{
    param($b)

    # Loop through all lines of input
    foreach($a in $b){

        if ($line = % 3)
            {
            Write-Output "divisible by 3"
         }
         else {
            Write-Output "number not divisible by 3"
         }   
        }
       } 


#Variables

#Get input from csv file
$a = Import-Csv "document 2.Dat"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$myarray=get-content C:\temp\test.csv | %{$_  -split " "} | %{if ($_ -match "\w+" -and ([int]$_ % 3) -eq 0) {[int]$_}}
```